# Solr: Field Cache using lots of memory inspite of enabling docValues="true" on fieldType for fields used for Faceting

Tags: solr

We are reading in the Solr Documentation that the Field Cache will be used if the docValues are not enabled in the fieldTypes.

We have enabled DocValues for all fields on which we are faceting on and reindexed all data as well. Went with default values for docValuesFormat so that it uses the default.

I have around 30GB memory and 20GB Heap space for the JVM. With this amount of heap space, we are still running into an OOM and when we analyzed the Heap dump, it shows 66% of the heap being used by the Jar.

My main question here is, Why is field cache using so much memory inspite of using docValues="true" while specifying the fieldType? Is this expected?

this is the schema version we are using

We do have a lot of facet fields and facet queries and same works well with solr 4, but not with solr 7.

```
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"   />
    <fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true" />

    <fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="pfloat" class="solr.FloatPointField" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="pdouble" class="solr.DoublePointField" docValues="true" />

    <fieldType name="pints" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
    <fieldType name="pfloats" class="solr.FloatPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
    <fieldType name="plongs" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
    <fieldType name="pdoubles" class="solr.DoublePointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
    <fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="pdates" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Comment: Are you using a schema version that supports docValues? (and is the field type of your field one that is supported for docValues in the Solr version you'åre using)

Comment: @MatsLindh I am using solr 7.3.1. Field Types we are using solr 7 for added to the original question. I have this line in the schema version<schema name="default-config" version="1.6">

Comment: Is this the same index as the one you ask about in "Solr 7 : High number of QueuedThreadPool threads when some requests hit solr"? In that question you say that you also facet on some text_general fields (which cannot be DocValued). If so, then those fields are the culprits. Look in your solr.log for UnInverting and see if the stats from the un-inversion has a very high term count.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, we removed those, but there were some other custom implementations which were culprits as well as very high amounts of requests asking for all facets without any filtering. Thank you @TokeEskildsen